# Jumping a ViewController in UINavigationController stack

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

As you see in the image above, I have a view controller (A) with a segue to a navigation controller. I want to perform that segue in away that takes me to view controller (B). I know that some of you will say just make a segue between (A) and (B), but it's not what I want.

I want to be able to go back not to (A) but to the previous view controller in the navigation controller stack.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options

1-

make the segue to the navigationController and in the VC that is before B , set a flag say in `viewDidLoad` and push VCB

2-

in code create a navigationController

```
let nav = /////

nav.viewControllers = [beforeBVC,VCB]
```

Comment: I like the second one. But I don't know how I would be able to go to VCB if I'm setting another VC before it in the nav.viewControllers. Is it possible or do I need to do more steps to do it.

Comment: VCB is at index 1 so it's top of the stack when you present it from the VC that is the source of the segue B will be the shown

Comment: the back will be shown to return from B to the VC before it

Answer (score 1):

This is just a modification to Sh_Khan answer. His answer was correct and I've tried both of his methods to achieve what I'm asking for and I succeeded.

However, I figured out that I don't really need to either create a navigation controller programmatically or to set a flag and check in viewDidLoad.

All I need to do is applying his second method inside the prepareForSegue function.

Example:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let navController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
    let BVC = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BVC")
    navController.viewControllers.append(BVC)
}
```

All the credits goes to Sh_Khan, since he is the one who really gave the answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe directly push the ViewController onto the navigation stack.

`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController2, animated: true)`